# Combining sento() write writev()?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, udp, sendto

I've set a udp socket and call sendto() with a different recipient at each call.

I would like to use writev() in order to benefit scater/gather io but writev() does not allows me to specify the recipient addr/port as in sendto(). Any suggestions?

Comment: are you wanting to use multiple recipients in each `writev` call, or just one?

Comment: @Alnitak just one per call to writev().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `writev` to send a coalesced set of buffers to a *single* end point if you use `connect` to specify the end point beforehand.  From the (OSX) manpage for `connect(2)`:

> datagram sockets may use connect() multiple times to change their association

You *cannot* use `writev` to send each buffer to a different endpoint.

A potential downside of using `connect / writev` instead of `sendto`**n* is that it is yet another system call per `writev`.

If the set of recipients is limited (and known in advance) it may be preferable to use a separate `socket` per recipient and just `connect` each socket once.

Comment: "If the set of recipients is limited (and known in advance) it may be preferable to use a separate socket per recipient and just connect each socket once." -> oh yeah, right, that's what we do now. Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, there is `sendmmsg(2)`

> The sendmmsg() system call is an extension of sendmsg(2) that allows the caller to transmit multiple messages on a socket using a single system call. (This has performance benefits for some applications.)

The prototype is:

```
int sendmmsg(int sockfd, struct mmsghdr *msgvec, unsigned int vlen,
             unsigned int flags);

struct mmsghdr {
    struct msghdr msg_hdr;  /* Message header */
    unsigned int  msg_len;  /* Number of bytes transmitted */
};
```

Since both the address and the i/o vector is specified in `struct msghdr`, you can both send to multiple destinations and make use of scatter/gather.